# como podría lograr este diseño usando bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap, responsivo

Tengo que hacer un diseño igual al de la foto, 5 contenedores organizados de esa forma. estoy usando bootstrap 4 y estaba haciendolo con el grid. en version de escritorio esta bien, pero cuando paso a movil todo se monta uno encima de otro, en version movil lo que quiero es que cada contenedor ocupe el 100% de la pantalla y queden uno debajo del otro, pero no me funciona. estoy haciendo uso de las clases ROW y COL con las medidas responsives pero no me funciona. no se si es por la forma en como lo estoy haciendo que no me funciona, por eso recurro a ustedes. Espero alguien pueda orientarme. Gracias de antemano. Este es mi codigo:

```html
<div class="row" id="fila-inmueble1" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-12" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <img class="img-fluid img-inmueble" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].fotos[0]}}" alt="inmueble1">
    <div class="info-inmueble">
        <h2 class="caracteristica"> <b class="text-blanco"> {{ this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].precio | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2'}} </b> </h2>
        <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/banera.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].bano}} </h2>   </span>
        <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/cama.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].habitacion}} </h2>   </span>
        <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/garaje.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].estacionamiento}} </h2>   </span>
        <p class="text-blanco text-helvetica titulo-inmueble" style="display: block;"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].nombre}}  </p>
    </div>
  </div>

    

  <div class="col-md-6 col-12" id="columna-derecha-fila1" style="width: 100%;" >
    <div class="row inmueble-columna2" style="height: 50%; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-12" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0;">
        <div class="info-inmueble">
            <h2 class="caracteristica"> <b class="text-blanco"> {{ this.hostlistService.inmuebles[2].precio | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2'}} </b> </h2>
            <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/banera.svg" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].bano}} </h2>   </span>
            <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/cama.svg" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].habitacion}} </h2>   </span>
            <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/estacionamiento.svg" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].estacionamiento}} </h2>   </span>
            <p class="text-blanco text-helvetica titulo-inmueble" style="display: block;"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[1].nombre}}  </p>
        </div>
        <img class="img-fluid img-inmueble" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[2].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[2].fotos[0]}}" alt="inmueble1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row inmueble-columna2" style="height: 50%; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-12" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0;">
          <div class="info-inmueble">
              <h2 class="caracteristica"> <b class="text-blanco"> {{ this.hostlistService.inmuebles[3].precio | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2'}} </b> </h2>
              <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/banera.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].bano}} </h2>   </span>
              <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/cama.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].habitacion}} </h2>   </span>
              <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/garaje.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].estacionamiento}} </h2>   </span>
              <p class="text-blanco text-helvetica titulo-inmueble" style="display: block;"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[3].nombre}}  </p>
          </div>
        <img class="img-fluid img-inmueble" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[3].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[3].fotos[0]}}" alt="inmueble3" style="padding: 0;">
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="fila-inmueble2" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-12" id="inmueble-fila2" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0;">
      <div class="info-inmueble">
          <h2 class="caracteristica"> <b class="text-blanco"> {{ this.hostlistService.inmuebles[4].precio | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2'}} </b> </h2>
          <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/banera.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].bano}} </h2>   </span>
          <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/cama.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].habitacion}} </h2>   </span>
          <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/garaje.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].estacionamiento}} </h2>   </span>
          <p class="text-blanco text-helvetica titulo-inmueble" style="display: block;"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[4].nombre}}  </p>
      </div>
      <img class="img-fluid img-inmueble" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[4].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[4].fotos[0]}}" alt="inmueble4">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-12" id="columna-derecha-fila1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0;">
    <div class="info-inmueble">
      <h2 class="caracteristica"> <b class="text-blanco"> {{ this.hostlistService.inmuebles[5].precio | currency: 'USD':true:'1.2-2'}} </b> </h2>
      <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/banera.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].bano}} </h2>   </span>
      <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/cama.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].habitacion}} </h2>   </span>
      <i class="ml-4 caracteristica"> <img class="icon-info-inmueble" src="../../assets/images/iconos/garaje.png" alt=""> </i> <span class="ml-2 caracteristica"> <h2 class="text-blanco"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[0].estacionamiento}} </h2>   </span>
      <p class="text-blanco text-helvetica titulo-inmueble" style="display: block;"> {{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[5].nombre}}  </p>
    </div>
    <img class="img-fluid img-inmueble" src="{{url}}{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[5].id}}_{{this.hostlistService.inmuebles[5].fotos[0]}}" alt="inmueble5">
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el diseño que quiero hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi es como se me muestra en version movil, observen que se solapan y se colocan uno encima de otro, lo que quiero es que quede uno debajo de otro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Editado, este es es el archivo CSS de esa componente:

```css
.cont-verDetalles {
 width: 100%;
}

#cont-preCarga {
 height: 300px;
}

.text-blanco {
  color: #f0f0eb;
}

#spinner {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

::ng-deep .carousel-control-prev {
  width: 70px;
}


::ng-deep .carousel-control-next {
  width: 70px;
}

#dropdown-buscar {
  background-color: #2e2046;
  color: #f0f0eb;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.div-redondo {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f0eb;
  border-color: #2e2046;
  border: solid 2px;
  padding: 0;
}

.nombrePais {
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}


#boton-paises-movil {
  display: none;
}

#cont-inmuebles {
  height: 900px;
}

#fila-inmueble1 {
  height:  600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#fila-inmueble2 {
  height: 300px;
}

.inmueble-columna2{
  height: 50%;
}

.info-inmueble {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.icon-info-inmueble {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, .8); 
}

.caracteristica {
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-md-6:hover .img-inmueble {
  background-color: #2e2046;
}

#inmueble-fila2 {
  height: 100%;
}

#columna-derecha-fila1 {
  padding: 0; 
  height: 100%;
}

#columna-derecha-fila1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.img-inmueble {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .7;
}

.img-inmueble:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.img-inmueble:hover .info-inmueble {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.text-morado {
  color: #2e2046;
}

.titulo-inmueble {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}

.text-precio {
  font-family: Futura,Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;

}

.text-helvetica {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.text-hot {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* ///////////////////////////// MEDIA QUERIES //////////////////////////////////*/

@media screen and (max-width: 971px) {

  #cont-paises button {
    display: none;
  }


  #cont-paises select {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    height: 42px;
    outline: 0; 
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #f0f0eb;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    border: 2px solid #2e2046;
    border-radius: 12px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
  }

  #cont-paises #icon-select {
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      top: calc(50% - 13px);
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      display: block;
      border-left:4px solid #2AC176;
      border-bottom:4px solid #2AC176;
      transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Giramos el cuadrado */
      transition: all 0.25s ease;   
  }

  


}
```

Comment: Estás usando clases propias, agrega las propiedades CSS que estás usando en dichas clases, pues con el código de Bootstrap tal cual lo muestras, no hace el diseño que muestras en tus imágenes

Comment: Acabo de agregar el .CSS a ver si con eso pueden ayudarme, gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: creo que si lees la documentacion de boostrap las medidas `sm md lg xl` son para los diferentes tama;os de pantallas....  documentacion https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: si las he leído, y si te fijas en el código html las estoy usando, el problema es que no se colocan uno debajo del otro en la versión móvil. no se si es que estoy haciendo mal en insertar filas dentro de columnas que a su vez están dentro de una fila, pero fue la solución que me ocurrió para ese diseño